# Pokemon Sun / Moon speed up gameplay

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Are there more options to speed up pokemon sun / moon?

I have found that you can disable battle effects and influence text speed in the options just like in most pokemon games.

http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Options

I am wondering if anyone knows of additional ways to speed up the game a bit. Any tips and hints would be greatly appreciated!

-- Edit

My question was meant for ingame as well as other ways for example i have read that certain 3DS's seem to run the game better (less loading time)

Answer (score 4):

I've looked around and I can't see anything other than what you have stated.

The only other way to speed the game is that you get given a Pokemon which has the ability to fly, flying around the map will significantly increase the game speed as it cuts down on all of the mindless walking you have to do to get around.

There is no bike in this game, however.

I apologize that I couldn't be much help here, I just don't think there are any other settings to speed up game, other than the ones you are already using.

Comment: Either I'm completely oblivious or there is no bike in sun/moon. Im leaning towards the latter because of the addition of the Pokémon Pager.

Comment: @Vemonus In the research I did I read somewhere that there was a bike, but if your sure there isn't I can take it out of my answer. I haven't played this version of pokemon

Comment: I believe the OT wanted to ask how to speed up the game performance maybe. He's talking about options..

Comment: well, kinda meant any way possible. i have read that certain 3DS's do perform better. i would recon the new ones that have more memory and therefore the loadtimes would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has stated the most obvious answers.

1. Use max repels to avoid wild pokemon. Note that they work better when the first pokemon in your party is a higher level than the wild pokemon in the area you are currently in.
2. Press B.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what pressing B does within the game

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Tauros ride you can press B to charge and go a bit faster.

I recommend you to put it at the cross panel so it’s faster to toggle it.